# Volatility Forecasting

Tags: volatility, implied-volatility

I would like to clear a certain doubt about volatility forecasting: Are models like Parkinson, Rogers Satchell and Yang Zhang used for predicting future volatility?

Comment: They model what's happened in the past (using various inputs like OHLC) - if you think this is representative of what's going to happen in the future, then yes, you can call that a forecast.

Comment: My impression is that they are currently not used too much. Range based volatility estimators are a bit complicated and were developed before the availability of high frequency data.

Comment: All these indicators are backward looking, but the ones based on high frequency (say 5 minute) data are closest to "what is happening now".

Answer (score 3):

From what I have seen yes. Yang & Zhang showed that their estimator is less biased and less volatile compared to the close-to-close estimator.
However, as mentioned, high-frequency data is probably better and is used by many. One good paper on this is the HEAVY-estimator from the Oxford-Man Institute (link here https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/multiHeavy.pdf).